# How to wait for maven test suite to finish before calling next command in batch file?

Tags: java, maven, batch-file, testing

I am building a test suite in which I need to call one `testng.xml` file which might take up to one hour to finish. Next I need to call python script to modify the results and go back to another `testng.xml` file. I want to put this all into a batch file but I don't know how to make a wait for the first script to finish running before calling the python script. Here is what I have so far and it executes properly. How do I insert wait?

```
set projectLocation=C:\myproject\pom.xml\location
cd %projectLocation%
mvn clean test -DsuiteXmlFile=testng.xml
```

After this I will need to go to python, call python and run another testng.xml. I have been trying loops as such with luck

```
:LOOP
tasklist /fo csv /fi "IMAGENAME eq regressionTestRunner.xml" 2>NUL | find /I /N "regressionTestRunner.xml">NUL

IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
  GOTO CONTINUE
) ELSE (
  echo Running
  Timeout /T 5 /Nobreak
  GOTO LOOP
)
:CONTINUE
```

Comment: If I remember correctly, the issue is lazy developers man pages, and lazy coding styles. `mvn` is really a batch file, I'll assume `mvn.cmd`, _(although it may still use the outdated `.bat` extension)_. Because it is a batch file, you should invoke it from another batch file using the `CALL` command. When you use the `CALL` command, that batch file should run, and only when it has completed, run the next line in your calling batch file. So, based upon your question content, I'd advise you just try `Call "%MAVEN_HOME%\bin\maven.cmd" clean test -DsuiteXmlFile=testng.xml`, then your next command.

Comment: Thanks Compo, using CALL command actually solves the issue

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because the man' pages from developers on command line tools are generally written to provide you with command lines written directly within the console window. For this reason they do not explain the proper usage, simply providing examples which can be entered with the minimum of typing. When you use a batch file, you are only typing your commands once, and as such have no need for this lazy typing style.

The first thing you need to be aware of is that `mvn` is not in itself a command. It is a shortened command which should technically refer to the executable batch file, `mvn.cmd`, *(although it may still use the outdated .bat extension, `mvn.bat`)*. Because it is a batch file, you should invoke it from another batch file using the `CALL` command. For information on this command, please open a Command Prompt window, type `call /?` and press the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key. When you use the `CALL` command, that batch file should run, and only when it has completed, run the next line in your calling batch file.

So, based upon your question content, I'd advise you try just:

```sh
@Set "projectLocation=C:\myproject\pom.xml\location"
@CD /D "%projectLocation%" 2>NUL || Exit /B
@Call "%MAVEN_HOME%\bin\maven.cmd" clean test -DsuiteXmlFile=testng.xml
@Rem Your next command here
```